# Dualboot second OS without formatting previous OS

Tags: sd-card, noobs, operating-systems

My PI 3 is currently running NOOBS on a Class 10 SD-Card.

---

I see multiple guides online, however I cannot find one that doesn't involve formatting the SD-Card.

I want to dual-boot another OS like Kali or Android (Emteria), aside from NOOBS.

**I do non want to format the card in order to preserve the current OS instillation**

How can I install another OS aside from my current one without formatting all the data and the OS installed?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer - you can't!

If you search this site you will find recommendations not to use NOOBS, and if you want multi-boot use [PINN](https://github.com/procount/pinn/blob/master/README_PINN.md)

Neither allows you to add OS after initial setup.

Long answer - (On Linux nothing is impossible) Using a Linux computer you can copy/shrink the OS partition; perform a fresh multi-boot install then restore the saved partition. There are a few adjustments to `fstab`, `cndline.txt` etc. required.